# slider height are not set for all container in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to set equal height for all sliders which has maximum height from slider of each container, so far its working fine. But the problem is, when i have multiple `.container`, height is taking from first one not each one, I want to set height for each container based on respective slider max height.

https://codepen.io/burner/pen/rZWdpN

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="grouping">
    <div class="responsive slider1">
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking.
    </div>
    <div class="responsive slider2">
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
    </div>
    <div class="responsive slider3">
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="grouping1">
    <div class="responsive slider4">
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
    </div>
    <div class="responsive slider5">
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
    </div>
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="slider6">
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
      Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container, .container2 {
  display: relative;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
function settingSliderHeight(){
    var $maximumHeight = 0;
    var $actualSlider = null;
    $('.container .responsive').each(function() {

        var $sliderHeight = parseFloat($(this).outerHeight());
        if ($sliderHeight > $maximumHeight) {
            $maximumHeight = $sliderHeight;
            console.log("$maximumHeight" + $maximumHeight);
            $actualSlider = $(this);
        }
        $(this).not($actualSlider).css("height", $maximumHeight);
    });
    $('.container .responsive').not($actualSlider).css("height", $maximumHeight);
}
   setTimeout(function(){
      settingSliderHeight();
    },2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery once

```
<script>
function settingSliderHeight(){
    var $maximumHeight = 0;
    var $actualSlider = null;
    $('.container').each(function() {

        var $sliderHeight = parseFloat($(this).outerHeight());
        if ($sliderHeight > $maximumHeight) {
            $maximumHeight = $sliderHeight;
            console.log("$maximumHeight" + $maximumHeight);
            $actualSlider = $(this);
        }
        $(this).find(".responsive").css("height", $sliderHeight);
    });

}
setTimeout(function(){
  settingSliderHeight();
},2000)
</script>
```